# How to zoom in a TextView?

Tags: android, textview, scrollview, zooming

I have declared the following xml code:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</ScrollView>
```

So, as you can I see, in the above `TextView` I set a huge amount of **immutable** text. I can slide both vertically and horizontally.

But, how I cant modify any of these elements to "pinch" the device to **zoom in and out** accordingly? Is there any library that can help me out?

Comment: Use a WebView, instead.

Comment: Is there any kind of guide, to guide me through?

Comment: If you google for `android webview`, you'll find a lot. In particular, the official docs should be the first result.

Comment: Has zoom functionality need any "special" handling? Or all is done automitically?

Comment: WebView does it automatically. Just feed the HTML to it. Either as a file or as an HTML content.

Comment: All right. And one more thing. If I use a WebView should I use the HorizontalScrollView and the ScrollView ?

Comment: No. It has its own scrolling system.

Comment: Check this : https://github.com/nomanr/ZoomTextView

Comment: @HareshChhelana: Why using a 3rd party library, when you can do he same by using an `out of the box` component?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `WebView` you could try using [`THIS`](https://github.com/nomanr/ZoomTextView) library, which is a custom TextView, when pinch in out gesture used, then it reizes text size.

Comment: Why using a 3rd party library, when you can do he same by using an `out of the box` component?